# How to set both a time and solution limit in OR-Tools?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, or-tools, cp-sat

I am using OR-Tools for some simple solving, but I am really confused on how you used `SolveWithTimeLimitSampleSat` and `StopAfterNSolutionsSampleSat`. I want the solver to try and find the 2 solutions, but I want it to stop after x amount of time if it hasn't found 2. The documentation on the google website is not helpful to say the least, it doesn't tell me the parameters for any of these functions nor an example. I tried using `VarArraySolutionPrinterWithLimit` but jupyter did not recognise this function, nor does my solver recognise either of the first 2 functions. Can anyone explain what I am meant to be placing in between the marked code below to get the aformentioned result?

```
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

    ### Something goes here ###

    status = solver.Solve(model)
    
    if status in [cp_model.OPTIMAL, cp_model.FEASIBLE]:
        for i in range(0, 30):
            print(f'{i + 1} is {solver.Value(Car[i]) + 1}')
    else:
        print('unsat')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explained in the docs directory.

Explicitly https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/solver.md

For instance, to set a time limit, just set a parameter after creating the solver and before calling solve:

```
    # Creates a solver and solves the model.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

    # Sets a time limit of 10 seconds.
    solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 10.0

    status = solver.Solve(model)
```

Comment: No it is not so that is why I am asking here:
`def SolveWithTimeLimitSampleSat():` this is not a definition, there is magically no parameters it just works?
`def SolveAndPrintIntermediateSolutionsSampleSat():` This isn't it either so don't say it is, there is no parameters defined to be passed, when I try run it it says that it is missing parameters or that it is not recognised.

Comment: why are you referencing functions defined in code samples? You should not call these methods, but transpose the code inside the methods into your code.

Comment: Are they callable functions or not then?

Comment: No. They are examples to demonstrate how to use the library. For instance `SolveWithTimeLimitSampleSat` shows you how to set the max_time_in_seconds parameters to limit the solve time.

Comment: So they are not functions build into the library?

Comment: No, they are part of the code samples that shows how to use the library.